# How to get file list from a Debian package using eptlib libraries?

Tags: c++, debian, apt

Simple question: I have loaded an Apt package record with libept. There is a method to get file list? It should sound like

```
 record.GetFileList();
```

and it should return a vector string like the output of

```
 dpkg -L packagename
```

Comment: ummm, isn't this a dup of your own http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341520/how-to-use-libapt-or-libept-in-debian-like-system-to-list-packages-and-get-thei

Comment: no.. this is about file "owned" by package enumeration.. the other post is about package listing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The libept main developer (Petr Rockai) explain me that unfortunately, at this time, libept have no such method. What they do in Adept is this:

```
QString flfilename = "/var/lib/dpkg/info/" + u8(t.package()) + ".list";
QFile flfile(flfilename);

QTextStream flInStream(&flfile);
while (!flInStream.atEnd()) {
   QString line = flInStream.readLine();
   // do stuff with line
}
flfile.close();
```