# Ruby wrapper for apt-get

Tags: ruby, package-managers

Is there a wrapper for package managers like apt-get and yum, written in ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Libept](http://www.mornfall.net/libept.html) may be a good place to start for an apt-ruby interface. (It's also been [discussed in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341520/how-to-use-libapt-or-libept-in-debian-like-system-to-list-packages-and-get-thei).)

Also, while it's maybe not exactly what you're after, [Cobbler](https://fedorahosted.org/cobbler/) and [Func](https://fedorahosted.org/func/) provide some pretty interesting functionality you can build on top of. (In particular, Func provides [a Python API to yum](https://fedorahosted.org/func/wiki/YumModule).)

Comment: Thanks! Neither are a direct answer, but it's an excellent starting point.