# Bash as a C lib?

Tags: c, bash

I've got a project where I want to do some stuff that would be trivial in bash but where I want/need a binary with has zero external dependencies. So, *has anyone written a self contained lib (i.e. not a wrapper around system()) that lets you do bash like stuff from inside C?*

Off hand, the things I expect to need are: `cp`, `rm`, `wget`, `tftp`, `ar`, `tar`, `guzip` and maybe `dpkg` but I think I can side step that one.

---

To answer the comments: I'm looking for something along the lines of a statically linked busy-box but where I don't need a shell file as a program for it and where things I don't use automatically don't even get linked in.

Comment: Most of these are external dependencies in bash... You want a single library with ALL of these executables embedded in the lib?

Comment: Why not just call `system("cp ...")`? (I'm assuming you're on Linux but this is a totally different question in Windows...)

Comment: Why can't you use system()? All of those are external executables, so having "bash as a C library" wouldn't help you to achieve zero dependencies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need [busybox](http://www.busybox.net/).

Comment: I could live with that, but would rather not. See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

I fully agree with [Busybox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765737/bash-as-a-c-lib/4765752#4765752). Additionally, if you get the source code for dpkg, you'll [find a small library inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115946/library-for-querying-installed-debian-packages-in-c/4116539#4116539) that gives you access to most of its functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of custom requirements, and as you say, you don't want "things I don't use don't even get[ting] linked in", so you're going to have to do a lot of hand-hacking.

If you compile all the external dependencies into object files, you *should* be able to link them in to your own tool (assuming no namespace conflicts; a big assumption, but not too bad if you're careful), you should be able to do it if you just excise their `main()` functions.

In fact, for the dependencies, you can probably even just rename their `main()`, and have the tool available to you as if you were calling it from the command-line yourself, by packing their argc/argv, though this would likely have some overhead, rather than calling the individual functions yourself.

The aforementioned `busybox` already offers all the features you require (even `tar` and `wget`) except for `dpkg`, and since there's already a lib for that, I'd say you're well on your way.

Comment: I was kind of hoping that someone had already done more or less exactly what you just described and then packed it as a lib.